# myDFPlayer does not play in do-while loop but works on its own

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm working on a project where a speaker turns on at sunset and plays until the given sunrise time using the DFPlayer mini module. I'm not super familiar with C++'s particular quirks so I'm running into a few issues. Namely, I am using RTCZero's alarm to jump to playing the speaker. If I include one myDFPlayer.play(1), it will play in the alarm just fine, but the minute I add any control structures the player becomes non-responsive. I've attempted to add delays approximately the length of my test clip (5 sec) to no avail. Currently I am trying to use the busy pin method on the DFPlayer but that is not working either.

Thanks for your help!

Here's my (admittedly messy and cobbled together) code. I'm working on an Adafruit Metro M0 Express. RX on the player is on pin 1, TX on pin 0, busy_pin on 2, VCC to 5V. The play function in setup works just fine as well.

I've attempted to stick delays before and after myDFPlayer.play() in the loop (either or both) and tried to use the busy pin to check if something is already playing. It prints everything up to "sunset" and then does not print any other checks.

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h"
#include <RTCZero.h>

#if (defined(ARDUINO_AVR_UNO) || defined(ESP8266))  // Using a soft serial port
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial softSerial(/*rx =*/4, /*tx =*/5);
#define FPSerial softSerial
#else
#define FPSerial Serial1
#endif

DFRobotDFPlayerMini myDFPlayer;
RTCZero rtc;

int busy_pin = 2;

const uint8_t sunriseMin = 5;

const uint8_t sunriseHr = 7;

/* Change these values to set the current initial time */

const uint8_t currentSeconds = 45;

const uint8_t currentMinutes = 02;

const uint8_t currentHours = 7;

/* Change these values to set the current initial date */

const uint8_t currentDay = 15;

const uint8_t currentMonth = 6;

const uint8_t currentYear = 15;


void setup() {
pinMode(busy_pin, INPUT);
#if (defined ESP32)
  FPSerial.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, /*rx =*/D3, /*tx =*/D2);
#else
  FPSerial.begin(9600);
#endif

Serial.begin(9600);
delay(1000);
Serial.println("begin");
rtc.begin();
rtc.setTime(currentHours, currentMinutes, currentSeconds);
rtc.setDate(currentDay, currentMonth, currentYear);
rtc.setAlarmTime(7, 3, 30);
rtc.enableAlarm(rtc.MATCH_HHMMSS);
Serial.println(rtc.getAlarmHours());
Serial.println(rtc.getAlarmMinutes());
rtc.attachInterrupt(alarmMatch);


if (!myDFPlayer.begin(FPSerial, /*isACK = */ true, /*doReset = */ true)) {  //Use serial to communicate with mp3.
  Serial.println(F("Unable to begin:"));
  Serial.println(F("1.Please recheck the connection!"));
  Serial.println(F("2.Please insert the SD card!"));
  while (true) {
        delay(0);  // Code to compatible with ESP8266 watch dog.
      }
 }

myDFPlayer.volume(2);  //Set volume value. From 0 to 30
myDFPlayer.play(1);
}


void alarmMatch(){
  Serial.println("sunset");
  do {
    myDFPlayer.play(1);
    if (!digitalRead(busy_pin)) {
      Serial.println("busy");
      delay(5000);
    }
  }while (rtc.getMinutes() != sunriseMin);
  Serial.println("exiting");
}


void loop(){
}
```